# Div content outside of div until refresh

Tags: css, html

I'm only having this issue with Chrome, and it doesn't happen when I run it locally only after checking it live on the web. Basically on the homepage, the bottom left containers content will be outside of the container, but when you reload the page it fixes it and is fine until you close the browser and open it again. Is it just a Chrome bug?

http://www.alttn.com

JFiddle
http://fiddle.jshell.net/nhpWJ/

Comment: It's a CSS bug. Your CSS is incorrect. Float the container and remove the 560 width... than it should be okay. From there, you can start styling again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `height` from `#pageWrap` and instead of using universal selector to center everything like this`* { margin: 0 auto }`, use a quick reset in the following way:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

For `#head`, add `margin: 0 auto` to center it.

```
#head, 
#footerContainer {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And finally apply `overflow:hidden` to `#bottom` so that your floated divs get layout.

```
#bottom {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 0 25px; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I know that some of my code was wrong, this was the first website I have coded and designed and all of what I learned has been from here and various other online sources.

Comment: Wow! Really? Glad to help you @Bucthree. Your footer is not centered right now. I will update my answer to fix that. Please check :)